# How to programmatically create a slot and slot a HTMLElement into it?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom, slot

I'd like to, without using HTML, create a slot and slot an element into it. I tried the following and a few variations but no luck. What am I doing wrong? Why is `slot.assignedNodes()` returning an empty array after I assigned the element?

```js
const element = document.createElement('div');
const slot = document.createElement('slot');
const slotted = document.createElement('span');

document.body.append(element);
element.attachShadow({ mode: 'open', slotAssignment: 'manual'});

element.shadowRoot.append(slot);
element.shadowRoot.append(slotted);

slot.assign(slotted);
console.log(slot.assignedNodes());
```

Comment: I can't even find documentation on what `.assign` is supposed to be used for. What are you trying to achieve and where do you read about it?

Comment: See my answer below; ``.assign(node)`` only works on ``<SLOT>`` elements **when** ``slotAssignment:"manual"`` is set. MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/assign

Comment: @TKoL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/assign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
element.shadowRoot.append(slot);
element.shadowRoot.append(slotted);
```

You are assigning `slotted` to the **same** shadowDOM the `<slot>` is in.
It should go to **lightDOM** with: `element.append(slotted)`

---

I rewrote your code so (I hope) its clearer

```js
const DIV = document.createElement('DIV');
DIV.attachShadow({ mode: 'open', slotAssignment: 'manual'});

const SLOT = document.createElement('SLOT');
DIV.shadowRoot.append( SLOT ); // Create SLOT in SHADOWDOM

document.body.append( DIV );

const SPAN = document.createElement('SPAN');
SPAN.innerHTML = "I AM SLOTTED";

DIV.append(SPAN); // put me in LIGHTDOM!

SLOT.assign( SPAN ); // only works because of slotAssignment:"manual" !!

console.log(SLOT.assignedNodes());
```

Without `slotAssignment:"manual"` you do **not** need `SLOT.assign(SPAN)` because **lightDOM** content will automagically be *slotted* to the default *unnamed* `<slot>`

#### With standard slot behavior

```js
const DIV = document.createElement('DIV');
DIV.attachShadow({ mode: 'open'});

const SLOT1 = document.createElement('SLOT'); // default slot
const SLOT2 = document.createElement('SLOT'); // slot name='title' !
SLOT2.name = "title";
DIV.shadowRoot.append( SLOT1 , SLOT2 ); // Create SLOTs in SHADOWDOM

document.body.append( DIV );

const SPAN = document.createElement('SPAN');
SPAN.slot = "title";
SPAN.innerHTML = "I AM SLOTTED in the SLOT name='title'";

DIV.append(SPAN); // put me in LIGHTDOM!

console.log(SLOT1.assignedNodes()); // nothing assigned to default slot
```